# Downloading php page as pdf in Codeigniter not working using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, pdf

I have a Codeigniter website, in it which has a view page and its values are coming from database. I want to download the page as pdf, i tried tcpdf and dompdf, but the issue is css and JavaScript is not working im these libraries. So i tried using jspdf like below:

```
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

```
<div class="container" id="content">
..........
</div>

<div id="editor"></div>



var doc = new jsPDF();
        var specialElementHandlers = {
     '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
        };

   $('#cmd').click(function () {
          doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
     doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
 });
```

Here the issue is, the pdf is getting downloaded but there is no data shown, a blank pdf is downloaded. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong here. Thanks in advance